# Error "You don't have docker-compose installed" but 'Docker Compose version v2.3.3' is installed

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, openvidu

Objective: install OpenVidu, using Docker-Compose onto a Ubuntu server.

Situation/Error: I believe I have docker-compose installed as when I run:

```
version docker compose
```

it gives me (as expected)

> Docker Compose version v2.3.3

However, when I enter in the command to install OpenVidu:

```
curl https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/aws.openvidu.io/install_openvidu_latest.sh | bash
```

I'm getting the error:

> You don't have docker-compose installed, please install it and re-run
> the command

[image: docker_not_installed]

Steps Taken:
Docker was installed by:

```
sudo apt install docker.io sudo 
systemctl start docker.service sudo
systemctl enable docker.service
```

Docker Compose was installed by:

```
mkdir -p ~/.docker/cli-plugins/
curl -SL https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.3.3/docker-compose-linux-x86_64 -o ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
chmod +x ~/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
sudo chown $USER /var/run/docker.sock
```

I'm new to Docker containers and likely missing something obvious. I've tried installing docker in different directories. I'm assuming that the relevant docker-compose.yml file is included when installing vidu.

Comment: I’m not familiar with `OpenVidu`, but the fact that the error message uses `docker-compose` (with a dash) suggests it might be expecting version 1.x, which was a stand-alone binary rather than a plugin.

Comment: `docker compose` (no dash) and `docker-compose` (with dash) are different. I think the no-dash version comes with Docker Desktop. I'm on Linux and I've only ever seen the dash version.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test but I think you've solved it! FWIW looks like Docker-Compose (1.x.x written in Python) is the older version, whilst Docker Compose (2.x.x written in Go) is the newer version, supposedly backwards compatible, but maybe not.... Vidu docs say I need at least version 1.24 so was compiled in the older version. I'll try retro reverting back and see. Thank you both, I never would have guessed that!

Comment: Yes, can confirm: OpenVidu local install requires 'Docker-Compose' and is incompatible with 'Docker Compose'. Given these were both super helpful comments, I'll mark as correct if either one of you would like to compose an official answer.

Answer (score 3):

**'Docker Compose' differs from 'Docker-Compose'**
Docker-Compose is required for on-prem installation of Vidu when following the instructions.

Docker-Compose (version 1.x.x written in Python) is the older version, whilst Docker Compose (2.x.x written in Go) is the newer version.

There are claims that Docker Compose is backwards compatible with Docker-Compose, but not in this case (see Pablo's response)

Thank you to **rimesc** and **Hans Kilian** who were the actual people to find the key to solving this.

Comment: Solution to the problem:  `apt install docker-compose`

Answer (score 0):

"docker compose" should be compatible with "docker-compose", but you must install Compose Switch, according to Docker documentation: https://github.com/docker/compose-switch

Comment: Following the documentation, just adding `sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin` work for me under ubuntu 22.04.